# how do I fix angular webpack karma [web-server]: 404: /[object%20Object] error

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, jasmine, karma-runner

Ok, so I downloaded the webpack angular zip file from https://angular.io/guide/webpack

used `yarn install`

then ran `yarn test`

and I get the following error. **NOTE**: no code has been edited / added. This is a fresh install from the above link.

[image: angular karma]

What is and where is the 404 error coming from.? I can't track down the `/[object%20Object]`

And excuse the obvious question but when running karma tests, is it normal for the browser (in my case, Chrome) to flash up and then disappear?

Comment: I guess angular advices `npm`. I've just did th exact same as you, and everything work as expected. `npm install`, and `npm test`. And the current `karma.conf.js` lets the test only runs once

Comment: @PierreDuc agreed - thanks. Put it up as the answer if you like